# What is com.apple.launchctl.Aqua?

Tags: macos, launchd

While troubleshooting a slow boot time in Lion (10.7), I saw these lines in the sys log:

```
8/21/13 8:47:45.102 PM com.apple.launchctl.Aqua: load: option requires an argument -- D
8/21/13 8:47:45.102 PM com.apple.launchctl.Aqua: usage: launchctl load [-wF] [-D <user|local|network|system|all>] paths...
```

So naturally I want to find out where this script is and why it has this error.  I searched the usual LaunchAgent and LaunchDaemon directories, and then searched the whole hard drive, but could not find a script by that name.

Answer (score 1):

com.apple.launchctl.aqua is `launchctl`. If you run strings over launchctl in /bin/launchctl it returns Aqua in amongst other strings.

I would say another script is trying to load and launchctl is failing to do so which is why you've got that error message.

I would list what processes are loaded and see if anything that is in your agent/daemon dirs isn't loading as expected.